# Cannot connect to SVN on Amazon EC2 server

Tags: svn, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've  installed SVN on EC2 instance following [these instructions](http://www.matt-helps.com/using-a-free-amazon-ec2-micro-instance-for-svn). The problem is that TortoiseSVN repository browser fails to establish connection to it. The URL I'm using is:

```
http://<my instance Public DNS>/<svn project root folder>
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's borderline programming I suppose...

Check your instance Security Group, making-sure port 80 is allowed through. Check the in-host firewall rules for the same. Check that whatever you're using to host web-access to SVN (Apache?) is running and listening on port 80. Check any local firewall and/or proxy rules you might pass through on the way out from your site to make sure port 80 is allowed to EC2 hosts.

Comment: the security group was not configured properly, correcting fixed the issue